# Combine lambda functions in Python

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, scipy

Is there a way to combine Python lambda functions into a new one?

I try to do the following (importing numpy as np):

```
zprime = lambda t: 2. / 3. * 2 * np.pi * np.cos(t * 2 * np.pi)
xprime = lambda t: 8. * np.pi * np.cos(t * 4 * np.pi)
yprime = lambda t: -8. * np.pi * np.sin(t * 4 * np.pi)
dL = lambda t: np.sqrt(xprime(t) ^ 2 + yprime(t) ^ 2 + zprime(t) ^ 2)
```

This produces an error message

Comment: When you get an error message, you should copy it in the question: error messages often give strong hints.

Comment: The ^ operator cannot be used on float64 values, and that are the values returning on your prime functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how you raise something to the second power

```
xprime(t) ^ 2
```

This is

```
xprime(t) ** 2
```

The `^` operator is the [`XOR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes like this demo;

```
x = lambda t: t**2
y = lambda z: z**2
h = lambda x,y: x**y

print (h(x(2),y(2)))
```

Result;

```
>>> 
256
>>>
```

Make sure you are using `**` for power.